# I am learning python and following along with a tutorial and i made this dice function but the continue = input() is being caught

Tags: python

https://github.com/Derek-Pruitt/py-test/blob/master/python%20game%20test/Dice.py**this is my code
I am having trouble with my code running it says that continue is not supposed to be there. what am I doing wrong I followed the tutorial exactly here is the link to the site**https://opensource.com/article/17/10/python-101

Comment: Please put the code directly in the question

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: You do know that `continue` is a keyword in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. There is no `=` in between the variable `continue` and `input()` on line 21.
2. You cannot use `continue` as a variable name, as it is a keyword, so basically you need to replace all those instances with another variable name.